# How to import customers with more than 2 address?

Tags: magento-1, import, address, user

I use a csv file to import customers into Magento.
This is the csv file header :

> website, email, group_id, group, firstname, lastname, password_hash, billing_firstname,  billing_lastname, billing_company, billing_street1, billing_street2, billing_city,billing_region,  billing_country, billing_postcode, billing_telephone,billing_fax, shipping_firstname, shipping_lastname, shipping_company, shipping_street1, shipping_street2, shipping_city, shipping_region, shipping_country, shipping_postcode, shipping_telephone, shipping_fax, created_in, is_subscribed

But if the customer have more than 1 billing / shipping address, which modification have I to do on the header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to modify the headers, you can just the extra shipping/billing address on a line after the primary shipping/billing address but you will simply need to include the commas for all other header details that are before and after the address details eg ",,,,City name, Telephone, etc..,,,,"

If your editing the csv file on excel(which isn't recommended) you can just add the address details for all address headers on the row below the row with the primary address details and leave all other details blank

Comment: If I add an other address on the row below the primary, the primary address is override.

Comment: That is odd, it works for me. Perhaps you have to add the headers _address_default_billing_ and _address_default_shipping_ and set one of the address as default

Comment: On the row with the other address, do you define the headers website and email ?

Comment: No i dont define anything except for the other address information

Comment: With address on a row below, it said that the row has been unheeded because the headers website and mail wasn't fill. If I fill these 2 headers, the primary addresses are overwrited. With the headers address_default_billing/shipping, nothing is done. Maybe there is a specific writing for these headers ?

Comment: So, it works now ! I exported customers from magento to have the exact headers. And the headers for addresses weren't the same as mine. And with it, I can add other addresses in rows below the primary =)

Comment: glad to hear it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

Use Magento Import/Export instead of Dataflow Profile.

Create ***multiple rows for addresses*** as in given screenshot.

I have just Exported and Imported it.

Hope it will help you.

**Find Screenshots for better understanding and let me know if more detail required.**

[image: CSV Example with multiple address]

[image: Use Import Export instead of Dataflow Profiles]